# Advantage of WPF app vs Winform for business apps?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I know asp.net and winform development. I am not the type of developer who jumps into a new technology just because it's new. It needs to give me extra benefits like higher productivity.

What are the advantages of WPF over Winforms for pure business apps? I am not interested in the extra eye candy, animation, gradients, image display effects and so on which WPF provides. The business apps are for data entry, data reporting and maybe some charts and  static display of photos.

How will WPF help in these apps? Better richer data binding? WinForm is a mature proven technology and I like the fact I can do everything in Visual Studio vs multiple IDE's for WPF (VS & Blend family). Plus I think WPF doesn't have as rich data binding controls like their Winform counterparts (DataGridView..etc). AFAIK, Microsoft will still support Winforms for many years.

Try to convince someone like me to switch.

Comment: I think there are some powerful reasons to switch to WPF. I don't want to repeat [a blog I've just written](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s308/wpf-winforms.htm), so will put a link to it here.

Comment: This is an excellent question. Should be reopened. I am a winform developers making a switch to WPF. The learning curve is huge. But WPF is the future, as it is declarative language by nature, like HTML. Winform is mostly procedural, which is more suitable for algorithms, but more verbose for displaying UI. Try unzip a .XPS print file, you will see WPF xaml there.

There are just too many limitations with Winforms. Though it still works, but the WPF "eye-candy" can help reduce user stress level. You can present multiple rows of record in more meaningful way other than listview or datagrid.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

> I know asp.net and winform development. I am not the type of developer who jumps into a new technology just because it's new. It needs to give me extra benefits like higher productivity.

For my team, WPF has proven to be much faster than WinForms to develop applications with. We recently released a mid-sized app in 32 man days. We had the advantage of an experienced WPF developer on the team, and inexperienced guys who were eager to learn the technology. There was great morale, and productivity was impressive.

> WinForm is a mature proven technology and I like the fact I can do everything in Visual Studio vs multiple IDE's for WPF (VS & Blend family).

Do you consider yourself a hand-coder, or a drag-and-drop coder? If you consider yourself a drag-and-dropper, than the current crop of WPF tooling may not be suitable for you. Maybe wait for Visual Studio 2010? I work almost exclusively in XAML. Most WPF'ers will probably agree that this is the most effective way of creating WPF applications at the moment. But then, I also craft my HTML by hand, so it feels natural to me...

> What are the advantages of WPF over Winforms for pure business apps? I am not interested in the extra eye candy, animation, gradients, image display effects and so on which WPF provides.

I used to think this way, but I have recently developed a business application which has gradients, basic animation and effects. These fancy features were added to enhance the user experience. Why should business apps be Battleship Grey? Why should they be unusable? Granted, it isn't color, gradients, animation that makes a business app usable, but using these effects can help the user experience, and this is what is important to me. I could have done everything I did in the WPF app in WinForms - it just would have taken much longer.

> Better richer data binding?

The databinding support truely is amazing. It is my single most-loved feature in the platform. Check out [this wonderful Databinding Cheatsheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf).

> Try to convince someone like me to switch.

I have decided that I am not going to try and convince anyone else to switch to WPF. The developers I have tried to "convince" (all experienced Winforms developers) usually have struggled with the platform. They are not invested in the technology. They don't "get it".
I encourage people to check out the technology to see if it is right for them as a developer. The learning curve is huge. If you learn by books, check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend/9919#9919) for some mini-reviews on WPF books. If you learn by videos, check out the [windowsclient.net WPF videos](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx). If you learn by example, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534328/good-example-wpf-applications) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837/what-real-world-wpf-applications-are-out-there) post. Forget everything you know about WinForms. WPF really seems closer to ASP than WinForms. Create some sample applications. See if it works for you and your team.

As you are multi-skilled (asp.net/winform skills), you may see the advantage of skilling-up in WPF as it is very closely related to Silverlight. Silverlight fills that gap between  your rich client applications and web applications.

I personally feel WPF is the best client side technology available for the .NET framework, and will generally avoid developing in WinForms for future work. YMMV

Comment: Awesome response Brad - our company is struggling with this decision right now.  Your observations are well thought out and very consistent with what we've seen so far.  We haven't come to a decision yet but your Battleship Grey paragraph resonates strongly with us as we've seen the impact a great looking UI has on sales.  

Thanks for taking the time to write an excellent answer.

Comment: True the answer is awesome. I was thinking of whether to start learning WPF or Windows Forms and this answer provided me lot of sides to think before deciding.

Comment: There is an enormous difference between having a single experienced WPF developer on a team and not having one at all. Couple that with steep learning curve and if you're running business you're not going to accomplish much at all. Realistically, WPF is great if you have someone to guide you and not so much if you're learning as you go. And if you do, get ready for major refactoring.

Comment: +1 - "Why should business apps be Battleship Grey?" - Completely agree!

Comment: I'm an experieneced WinForms developer and still struggle with it. It's so incredibly behind other MS tech like EF, it needs too much extra work. It was find with plain ADO.NET, but I'm sure as hell not going back there.

Comment: -1 If the only reason to move to WPF is based on the ability to create gradients and change your application dialogs from "battleship grey" then you need to actually learn how to use WinForms.

Comment: +1, through-full answer. The link  windowsclient.net WPF videos is down, anyone knows where to find those ?

Answer (score 11):

I have quite a bit of winforms experience and have only played with WPF a little bit, but I'm sold.

Why?

- MUCH more flexibility. If you want to do anything non-standard in winforms, pain and suffering ensues, but in WPF it's simple.
- Much better databinding
- Easier to develop (once you understand the core concepts, which unfortunately will take a while)

Answer (score 4):

When I started looking at WPF, I treated it as "Winforms with Vector Graphics" and ran straight into the side of the learning cliff. The proper way to transition from WinForms to WPF is to take a heroic dose of whatever narcotic you can lay your hands on in order to forget everything you know, then start from scratch.

Seriously though - it's a lot cleaner and easier if you use a pattern such as Model-View-ViewModel. Read more at [The Orbifold](http://www.orbifold.net/default/?p=550), this [Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/3fe270cd107f184f?pli=1) and [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/MVVM/)

Then at some point you'll have an epiphany and start databinding everything. Your code-behind will become not much more than a call to InitializeComponent().

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the post. My company has tons of time invested in WinForms. I can't imagine getting a medium sized application out in 32 man days; our certification periods are months on end and release cycles sometimes yearly or longer (despite sticking as close to an Agile development philosophy as we can), such is the nature of the applications we develop.

I just played with WPF for the first time and found I can get some benefits of WPF in WinForms by using ElementHost. I extended a WPF TextBox, then wrapped my extended class in a Win Forms UserControl and now have a WinForms app using that WPF text box, complete with spell check support.

I'm impressed to see Microsoft thought of this (hosting WPF in WinForms and vice versa), since I really can't see my company moving to WPF unless we can transition over a long period of time; there's just too much invested in WinForms to start again. With my recent experience I may begin to talk to some other developers about my recent experience and see what their thoughts are. I think WPF will take some time getting used to and that seems consistent with other comments.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a duplicate but you may find this post helpful about the benefits of WPF aside from the new graphics bits.

[WPF or WinForms for internal tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627590/wpf-or-winforms-for-internal-tools)

Answer (score 0):

Just check this search results right here in Stackoverflow to get numerous answers. 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WPF+Winforms

Comment: I hope you think that I tried that already!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you could use the same UI(XAML) from your ASP.NET/(Silverlight) page with your desktop app.  You'd only build it once but wire it to either....that's one of the intents of WPF/XAML...are we really there yet?  Not yet but getting closer.

Comment: Trying to use the same UI in silverlight and a desktop app is one of those things that sounds nice in theory, but in practice I think will just lead to a crappy UI on both platforms.

Comment: Yeah, the overlap between WPF and Silverlight2 is large, but not enough to make your code portable. Differences in binding capabilities will restrict your WPF development excessively.

Comment: Well I did say we aren't quite yet there...but that's the ultimate intent.

Comment: geofftnz: did you mean restrict *Silverlight* development?