# Why Asp.net MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Advantage of WPF app vs Winform for business apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636028/advantage-of-wpf-app-vs-winform-for-business-apps)
>   [Biggest advantage to using ASP.Net MVC vs web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms)

I have a silly question here. **Asp.net web form has tool box which helps you to drag the tools rather than writing codes for tools.** but there is no such options in asp.net mvc2. we have to write codes for tools.

My question here, why this complicated method ( writing codes for tools) which is time consuming become popular??? and this web forms are outdated now. what is the advantage of asp.net mv2. i simply don't understand. can u explain me.

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms

Answer (score 2):

Webforms isn't as "drag and drop" as you make it out to be:  you still have to set properties on the controls, and there's still a lot of complexity involved in hooking them all together.  This is especially true as you start building your own controls.  If you're not messing around in the markup for web forms, you probably haven't worked on a project of any real complexity. MVC has html helpers that do almost as much of the work for you, and do it in a way that more naturally matches the target html.

There are also some big "gotchas" in web forms that just don't exist for MVC: ViewState, dynamic controls, the one big form limitation, broken back buttons... I could go on and on.

Answer (score 0):

I think its all about personal preference I personally like the MVC framework because its what I'm most familiar with.  Here is a blog post with some more in depth reasoning [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/07/09/asp-net-mvc-vs-asp-net-web-form.aspx).