# A fun programming language for graphical application development

Tags: programming-languages

I am not a professional programmer, and I don't stand to become one in the near future. I code mostly for fun, but I do like to create programs that I'm actually going to *use*, and that means mostly graphical programs. I started out with Java and Python, but for the past few years I've ended up almost exclusively using JavaScript, simply because it's so easy to put together an interface in HTML, and the API for controlling the display and receiving input is very easy (especially with jQuery).

However, JavaScript is limited (no real file IO, APIs for eg complex graphics via canvas are awkward, have to run it in a browser) and also not a particularly pretty or powerful language. I miss the more powerful features from more fleshed out languages that I've used (Java, Haskell, Ada). Thus I'm in the market for a new language. But it needs to be something that makes it easy to build *graphical* applications.

Can anyone recommend a good high-level language, maybe a scripting language, or possibly a more heavy duty programming language that doesn't distract too much from the more interesting aspects of development? Or am I stuck with making web apps?

Comment: WPF, WPF and more WPF (this is .Net and the language is primarily XAML + C#). Check [this video](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** `.Net` (Applies if you're interested in doing Windows applications)

In contrast to @Branyac's answer, I recommend that you rather skip the winforms part and go straight to the current, relevant technologies (XAML-based)

It makes no sense for anyone to start learning winforms right now in 2013, because:

- it's outdated. No one is using it for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.
- it doesn't support a deep level of customization (like what you can find in WPF via `ControlTemplates`.
- it does not (natively) support many interesting visual features (such as `Animations`)
- It's software rendered, it does not support hardware acceleration, therefore many visually intensive applications are impossible to be done in winforms.
- It doesn't expose advanced `DataBinding` features, requiring you to type more code and achieve less.
- It doesn't expose any kind of [Document APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx), therefore many of the things you might be used to easily achieve in HTML are much harder in winforms.
- It doesn't support the state-of-the-art development patterns currently being pushed towards by the community in general ([MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)), thus again requiring more code to achieve less.
- It does not (natively) support [UI Virtualization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA) which can really be a game changer if you handle high volumes of data.

Instead of having to deal with such a limited UI technology, I recommend using any of the XAML-based technologies Microsoft has been actively developing in the last 5 / 6 years, namely:

- [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms754130.aspx) (Windows Presentation Foundation).

  - Runs on Windows XP and above, requires the .Net Framework. Has full power. is XAML based.
- [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838158(v=vs.95).aspx)

  - Cross-platform, runs in the browser, is also XAML based, has a more limited power, has a subset of the WPF features.
- [WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx)

  - Runs in Windows 8 and above, is also XAML based. Also contains a subset of the WPF features.

The advantages of using current technologies are endless, some of which are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/636921/643085), and all over the web.

In addition to all of the above, your HTML background will really help you in getting the XAML mentality. XAML is a markup language as well as HTML, but with much more features. You use XAML to define the UI in WPF and then databind the UI to relevant ViewModels and Models containing data.

The winforms approach is too procedural and requires a lot of boilerplate code everywhere. I would say that it does not `make it easy to build graphical applications`.

**Option 2:** Keep going the HTML + Javascript way.