# Use a bitmap image as a main window in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, bitmap

I was creating a Windows Forms based application in C#. I want to display a custom main UI. I have a source Bitmap image for the same. But I cannot find the solution so as to how to do this in C#.

[Here](http://i299.photobucket.com/albums/mm298/aabond/_main_zps6e6cfdd1.png) is my main window for the UI in which I would display the buttons and the display.

Can anyone tell me how to do this??

Thanks.

Comment: Displaying is simple but you have also to support some **interactivity** such as interactivity with the Close, Maximize, Minimize buttons, Sizing borders, ...

Comment: Won't the windows form adjust the sizing adjust the sizing of the Bitmap Image when it is inserted as is??

Comment: I don't really understand what you want with just an image? Your image even contains some links so looks like that's just what you should design to mimic, using that image on your form makes no sense.

Comment: @KingKing: I just uploaded this image as an example. I would be using a different one (can't share that one to you though ;)).

The image would just make the UI appear more _fresh_

Comment: Anyway as I said how to make your image **interactive** is the most difficult thing, showing it (as a static image) is easy.

Comment: @KingKing You're damn right. This would involve resizing the image every time the form gets resized, something which is just not possible IMO.

Comment: This question is far too broad. It also has no code, you've tried nothing and it's something you could easily Google.

Comment: @Jhawins I have done my share of homework.

Comment: @HarshitSuri please show us your homework. What have you tried? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using WinForms, you must use WPF.

Some links (there are many helpful resources, check on google for more):

- [WPFtutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/Home.html)
- [Designing with Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511329.aspx)
- [Advantage of WPF app vs Winform for business apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636028/advantage-of-wpf-app-vs-winform-for-business-apps)